# Has anyone found a workaround the IMemoryBlobStream.LoadFromFile() error

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.0

As far as I am aware, you will get an error if you try to load large file sizes using the function IMemoryBlobStream.LoadFromFile().

Has anyone found some workaround code to load a file into a IMemoryBlobStream?

What I am trying to do is just insert a PDF document file into a BLOB in an Oracle database, but I am not, and do not want to use Oracle API's.  I am just using ArcOjects for this one.

My code looks like:

```
public void LoadReport(string fileName)
{
    try
    {
        if (File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            IMemoryBlobStream2 memoryBlobStream = new MemoryBlobStreamClass();
            memoryBlobStream.LoadFromFile(fileName);

            report = memoryBlobStream;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
                throw ex;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

This is the code I have put to finally get the file in the database, now just need to check reading out the file from the BLOB - hopefully it should work.

```
fs = new System.IO.FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

byte[] bytes = new byte[fs.Length];

int chunkSize = 2 << 17;

int pos = 0;

for (pos = 0; pos < (fs.Length - chunkSize); pos += chunkSize)
{
    fs.Read(bytes, pos, chunkSize);
}
long modResult = (fs.Length % chunkSize);
fs.Read(bytes, pos,Convert.ToInt32(modResult));

IMemoryBlobStream2 memoryBlobStream = new MemoryBlobStreamClass();
memoryBlobStream.ImportFromMemory(ref bytes[0], (uint)bytes.Length);

fs.Close();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, load the file into a regular .NET `Stream` (e.g. a `FileStream`), then convert it to `IMemoryBlobStream` as follows:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[stream.Length]; // stream is a .NET Stream instance
stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

IMemoryBlobStream memoryBlobStream = new MemoryBlobStreamClass();
memoryBlobStream.ImportFromMemory(ref bytes[0], (uint)bytes.Length);
```

In your specific scenario you can take a handy shortcut of reading the `bytes` in a simpler way, by calling [File.ReadAllBytes()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx). It opens, reads and closes a FileStream behind the scenes for you.

Any other instance of a .NET `Stream` will do the trick, of course.

In any case, this approach is more memory-intensive than `IMemoryBlobStream.LoadFromFile()` as the data will need to reside in the memory twice before the GC collects the `bytes` reference.

Comment: This looks great - and a very good explanation.  I tried this and it looked like it was working - but when reading into the byte array - it threw an exception "Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service."

Comment: How large is the binary data?

Comment: Well the PDF is about 200mb - but some of the filess are only 23mb.  It seems that any files less that 23mb have worked but the larger ones fail.

Comment: Hmm.. don't think I can help you with this one. I've never had problems with this approach. In your case it probably fails for the same reason IMemoryBlobStream.LoadFromFile() does in the first place. This could occur when a continous block of the requested memory is not available due to memory fragmentation.

Comment: Unfortunately, ESRI forces us to use an intermediate in-memory blob representation without a means to use chunked transfer instead...

Comment: Oh dear, how depressing.  But thanks for trying anyway.

Comment: I also forgot to say that this is running in a vitual machine - but it has been allocated lots of memory, around 1.5GB.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the VM's memory allocation? Try 3-4GB.

Comment: I've never tried it, but looks like a [Memory Mapped file](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/salvapatuel/archive/2009/06/08/working-with-memory-mapped-files-in-net-4.aspx) might help.  I think this is only for .NET 4 though.  Hopefully there'll be a service pack that supports 4 soon.  Other memoryblobstream issue [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/12047).

Comment: I have tried increasing the memory - no diff.  However inbetween times - I think I am getting some success.  I am just trying to read the BLOB out of the database now - if that works and can show a PDF again - I've cracked it.  If so I will post code.  Kind of excited!!

Comment: That reminds me, the IMemoryBlobStreamVariant.ImportFromVariant is perhaps a bit cleaner and safer in .NET than IMemoryBlobStream.ImportFromMemory. But I suspect that the issue will remain the same.

Comment: @Vidar: if you have direct access to the database, then go that way if there are no administration, security or architectural concerns involved. Both ODP.NET (preferred) and MS's (which is now obsolete) ADO.NET Oracle Providers can work with BLOBs in a buffered chunked manner. Just be careful how you work with the data in case they are versioned.