# How to serialize IStyleGallery Object?

Tags: arcobjects, c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I store an ArcObject inside a BLOB or XML field?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8453/can-i-store-an-arcobject-inside-a-blob-or-xml-field)

I am saving shape file in database and now i want the symbology selected for the feature layer also get stored in database. I am facing an issue I cannot serialize IStyleGallery, and if its not serialized than how can i store that in database. Anyone got any good solution?

Answer (score 3):

Just to clear things up, [`IStyleGallery`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//001w00000322000000) has nothing to do with the symbology ([feature renderer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000468000000)) of a particular feature layer. Additionally, interfaces cannot be serialized, only class instances (objects), and in ArcObjects, typically only those that implement [`IPersistStream`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//004200000173000000) or [`IXMLSerialize`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//00420000026z000000). You might also consider simply storing a [layer file](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000000w8000000), if you are also storing shapefiles wholesale.

Comment: Thankyou for your response, Do you have any better approach? I want to load `feature layer` from the database. I have stored shape file (.shp, .prj, .shx ...) in database. While uploading shape files i took symbology but how to store the symbology data in database and again reload and apply it to the layer?

Comment: Since this question already has a couple of votes to be closed I would suggest creating a new question for that, and don't forget to add all the necessary details such as what database, what the server and client software, platforms and versions are, etc. Basically fully explain your situation so that people aren't guessing about what you are trying to accomplish and with what tools. Some good tips for asking a great question can be found here: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints